# Update the library to a specific version

Tags: go, go-modules

This is the version of golang.org/x/net library I am using

```
golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20181005035420-146acd28ed58
```

v0.0.0 is a release(it means there is no release)
20181005 is the time for commit
146acd28ed58- short for commit id
what is 035420 in the middle of the version?
The issue I want to upgrade this library to

```
https://github.com/golang/net/commit/7e3656a0809f6f95abd88ac65313578f80b00df2
```

So I derived the following part:

```
   golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20200506       -7e3656a0809f
```

I can't find what should be in the middle?

Comment: Don't try to generate the pseudo-version, just `go get` the commit you want.

Comment: Thank you, put this as an answer I will accept it thank you @JimB

Comment: If you're still curious: 035420 is the commit time in UTC (just before 4 AM).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Go Wiki: Modules: How to Upgrade and Downgrade Dependencies:](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-upgrade-and-downgrade-dependencies)

> To upgrade or downgrade to a more specific version, 'go get' allows version selection to be overridden by adding an @version suffix or ["module query"](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_queries) to the package argument, such as `go get foo@v1.6.2`, `go get foo@e3702bed2`, or `go get foo@'<v1.6.2'`.

So in your case just run:

```
go get golang.org/x/net@7e3656a0809f6f95abd88ac65313578f80b00df2
```

See related: [Go modules pulls old version of a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722865/go-modules-pulls-old-version-of-a-package/57722999#57722999)