# Go project not pulling import updates from github

Tags: go, versioning, dependency-management, go-modules

I have a package `hello` which contains the files `go.mod` and `hello.go` and a package `say_things` with files `go.mod` and `say_things.go`.

`hello.go`:

```
package main

import "github.com/user/say_things"

func main() {
        say_things.SayBye()
}
```

`say_things.go`:

```
package say_things

import "fmt"

func SayBye() {
        fmt.Println("BYE")
}
```

Both these projects are github projects. When I run `hello.go`, it prints "BYE" as expected. I now update `SayBye` to be:

```
package say_things

import "fmt"

func SayBye() {
        fmt.Println("GO AWAY")
}
```

and push the changes to github. I again run `hello.go`, expecting it to say "GO AWAY", but it doesn't. It still says `BYE`. I remove the `go.sum` generated and `go run hello.go` again, but still it says `BYE`. I then go to `go/pkg/mod/github.com/user/` and delete `say_bye@v0.0.0-<hash>`, and run `hello.go` again. Still, nothing changes. Next, I run `go get github.com/user/say_things`, still I get `BYE`.

How do I get `hello.go` to run the updated `say_hello` code?

Comment: Run the go get command with the update flag: `go get -u github.com/user/say_things` to get the updated package.

Comment: Also, `go.sum` does not dictate the version, it only records the checksums. `go.mod` is what defines the version you are using.

Comment: @MuffinTop Forgot to mention in the post, I did that too, didn't work.

Comment: @JimB Deleting the versions in `go.mod` worked, thanks! Is there a way to automatically pull updates?

Comment: @picotard: `go get -u` will check for updates, but your random commit ids on master do not constitute "updates". If you want a specific commit, you need to `go get` that commit.

Comment: Once you reach `v1.0` and you push new commits after that, `go get -u` will not fetch them. You have to use `go get foo/bar@master`. See [Go modules pulls old version of a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722865/go-modules-pulls-old-version-of-a-package/57722999#57722999).

Comment: I wish there was a way to specify pulling from master in `go.mod` instead of from a specific version or commit, but it seems like `go get -u github.com/user/say_things@master` works well for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to update your code by doing the following change.

Open your `go.mod` file in your `hello` project and `replace` the `current version` written against `github.com/user/say_things` with the last commit hash of your `say_things` project.

In other words, in `go.mod` file 
Replace `github.com/user/say_things <current-version>` 
with `github.com/user/say_things <last-commit-hash>`

And finally run:

```sh
$ go mod tidy
$ go mod vendor
```

Comment: What is the purpose of adding the vendor directory?

Comment: If you want to keep all your dependency inside your project, `vendor` directory will do the job. If you don't want `vendor` directory, you can just run `go mod tidy`.

Answer (score 4):

[go get](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Add_dependencies_to_current_module_and_install_them) command downloads new version of required module.
For example:

```
% go get -u all

go: github.com/user/say_things upgrade => v0.0.0-<new hash>
```

– download all last module's version to `$GOPATH/pkg` and upgrade `go.mod` file.

❕When using [go-modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules), the better approach is adding version tags to repository (`tag` have to
fit to [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org) specification)

```
git commit -a - m "say_things - some changes"
git tag v1.0.1
git push
git push --tags
```

This will allow you to manual change versions in `go.mod`

```
module github.com/user/hello

go 1.15

require github.com/user/say_things v1.0.1
```

```
% go mod download 

go: finding github.com/user/say_things v1.0.1
```

, and get required version by version tag

```
% go get github.com/user/say_things@v1.0.1

go: finding github.com/user/say_things v1.0.1
go: downloading github.com/user/say_things v1.0.1
go: extracting github.com/user/say_things v1.0.1
```